# How to use serial.available twice in void loop?

Tags: arduino-ide, keypad, arduino-c++

I am using keypad(4x4) with arduino nano and then serially communicating arduino nano and nodemcu. My code for arduino nano is:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Password.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
Password ssid = Password( "1234" );
Password pass = Password( "56789" );
Password connection = Password( "C" );

const byte ROWS = 4; // Four rows
const byte COLS = 4; // Three columns

char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = { 2,3,4,10 };
byte colPins[COLS] = { 11,7,8,9 };
Keypad customKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );
SoftwareSerial s(5,6);
//void checkPassword();
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  s.begin(9600);
  customKeypad.addEventListener(keypadEvent); //add an event listener for this keypad
  Serial.println("enter SSID: ");    
}

void loop()
{
  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey(); //storing pressed key value in a char
  if (customKey) {
    if(s.available() > 0) {
      switch (customKey) {
        case '1':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          break;
        case '2':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          break;
        case '3':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          break;
        case '4':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          break;
        case '5':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          break;
        case '6':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          break;
        case '7':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          break;
        case '8':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          break;
        case '9':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          break;
        case '0':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          //s.write("\nPassword verified\nPress C to connect\n");
          break;
        case '*':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          //s.write();
          //s.write("\nSSID verified\nEnter your Password\n");
          //checkPassword();
          break;
        case '#':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          break;
        case 'A':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          break;
        case 'B':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          break;
        case 'C':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          //s.write("\nConnecting to..");
          break;
        case 'D':
          Serial.println(customKey);
          s.write(customKey);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}

void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent key){

  switch (customKeypad.getState()) {
    case PRESSED:
      // Serial.println(key);
      //s.write(key);
      switch (key) {

        case '*': 
          checkPassword();
          break;

        case '#': 
          ssid.reset();
          pass.reset();
          connection.reset();
          break;

        default: 
          ssid.append(key);
          pass.append(key);
          connection.append(key);
      }
  }
}

void checkPassword(){

  if (ssid.evaluate()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("SSID verified");
    Serial.print("enter password: ");  
  } else if (pass.evaluate()){ 
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Password verified");
    Serial.println("press C to connect"); 
  } else if (connection.evaluate()) { 
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Connecting to....");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Wrong");
  }
}
```

and my nodemcu code is:

```cpp
#include <String.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
SoftwareSerial s(D6,D5); // (Rx, Tx)
String shab;
String shab2;
String arr[40];
String arr1[40];
const char* shab1="";
const char* shab3="";
std::string str;
int i,k;

void setup() {
  s.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("enter ssid: ");
}

void loop() {

  s.write("s");
  while(s.available() >0) {
    char data=s.read();
    shab += data;
    Serial.print(data);
  }

  int len=shab.length();
  if (shab.charAt(len-1)=='*') {
    for(i=0;i<shab.length();i++) {
      arr[i]=shab.substring(0,len-1);
    }
    shab1 = arr[0].c_str();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println(shab1);
    Serial.print("Enter ur password: ");
    // delay(7000);


    // while(true){
    while(s.available() >0) {
      char data1=s.read();
      shab2 += data1;
      Serial.print(data1);
    //}
      int len1=shab2.length();
      if(shab2.charAt(len1-1)=='*') {
        for(k=0;k<shab2.length();k++) {
          arr1[k]=shab2.substring(0,len1-1);
        }
        shab3 = arr1[0].c_str();
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println(shab3);
        Serial.println("Connecting to wifi: ");
        delay(2000);
        Serial.println(shab1);
        Serial.flush();
        WiFi.begin(shab1,shab3);
        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
          delay(500);
          Serial.print(".");
        }
        Serial.println(" IP address: ");
        Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
        delay(2000);
       // } 
      } 
    }

    while(1) {
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

Now the problem is that when i enter the password from keypad, this while(s.available>0) line when given second time, it does not work. This does not print anything on the serial monitor. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after `Serial.print("Enter ur password: ");`, the program immediately evaluates `s.available()`. Since nothing is available, it goes into the infinite loop at the end of `loop()` and never gets out of it.

If you want to read incoming data until you receive `'*'`, you can do something like this.

```cpp
Serial.print("Enter ur password: ");

bool entered = false;
while (entered == false) { // loop until entered becomes true
    yield();
    while (s.available() > 0) {
        char data1 = s.read();
        shab2 += data1;
        Serial.println(data1);
        int len1 = shab2.length();

        if (shab2.charAt(len1-1) == '*') {
            // do whatever you need to do
            entered = true;  // now you can get out of the loop
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: i added this while loop so that void loop runs only once

Comment: second time while(s.available>0) is mentioned, it takes values only until delay is added. For eg. if i add a delay of 5sec, then it will receive data from keypad only for 5sec and print it on serial monitor. Suppose if i want to enter 15 digits from keypad then what should i do? I cannot keep increasing the delay.

Comment: Ah, I guess I did not understand what you wanted to achieve. Do you at least see ""Enter ur password: " printed on your serial monitor?

Comment: yeah.. i see that.. but after seeing "enter your password" on serial monitor, i press the button from keypad, but it does not show anything.

Comment: this solution actually worked but it shows some error in the serial monitor. This is the picture of the error: https://imgur.com/a/Ljd4hhY

Comment: You are getting WDT reset. ESP8266 enables WDT by default. Try putting yield(); in the while loop.

Comment: In case you are wondering where to insert yield(), I updated the answer. Let me know if this works.

Comment: where you have updated your answer? I mean where should i insert yield?

Comment: after ```while (entered == false)```.

Comment: actually can you help me with the other code? @Kentaro Okuda    This is the link to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55946551/cannot-connect-to-wifi-network-through-webpage